# Tooltip-Popup disappears too fast for "people you'll work with"

Tags: support, design, stack-overflow-jobs

I clicked on a [job advertisement](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/gini-gmbh) and scrolled down. In the dark-grey banner of people I would work with, I cannot see profile names or pictures.

When I hover over the items, I can see the profile name, tags and a link to the profile page. **BUT** if I want to click the link to navigate to the profile the tooltip disappears. I did not find any possibility to follow the link.

[image: link in popup unclickable]

My environment:

- Firefox 46.0.1
- Windows 7 professional
- behind company firewall that blocks https://i.stack.imgur.com

Internet Explorer 11 works fine.

Comment: You simply slide the mouse down from its current position. If its current position toggled the pop-up, then sliding it down will position the cursor on the pop-up itself, which will keep it visible.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I'm guessing you're using an outdated browser on an outdated Windows version, going by your screenshot.

Comment: @CodyGray There is a gap between the dark grey banner and the popup. If I slide the mouse down I get into that gap and the popup disappears.

Comment: I can't repro that on my machine. Yes, there's a gap there, but it is visual only; it doesn't affect hot-tracking behavior. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: @Stijn my firefox browser is not too old, but the company's firewall could cause the issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your browser is [not officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), but that's probably not the cause.

The actual cause will be the firewall; see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81383/167646) for a list of domains and subdomains that need to be whitelisted.

The page should look like this:

> [image: screenshot of page]